# selenium python webcrawl - failing hard idk why

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

So i have a website below that i want to web-crawl

https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords=&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1=66&search_cat2=0

So essentially i would like to download the thumbnail and the titles, including the green and yellow buttons on the side (metadata)

I tired to run a for loop on the

```
<li>list</li>
<li>list</li>
<li>list</li>
<li>list</li>
```

lists below but kept on failing unable to move down to the part i want to download due to either my incompetence or inconsistant ID/Class name DOM

I attempted something similar below in an attempt to move down the DOM hierachy using the ID but for some reason it kept on failing. Would appreciate any help. Stuck for almost a day. my brain is melting

How do i move down the DOM hierachy. Given that the website used ID/Class all the way down till suddenly they start using something else

```
postContainer = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                '//*[@id="post_list2"]/li')
            for li in postContainer:
                print('Thumbnail', li.find_element_by_css_selector(
                    'img').get_attribute('src'))
                print('Location MetaData', li.find_elements_by_id_(
                    '.main_col>.left_col>.post_list2').get_attribute("title"))
                print('Etc Metadata', li.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                    '.info>.meta clearfix>.cat-category2').get_attribute('title'))
                print('상품명', li.find_element_by_css_selector('h3.title').text)
```

original code is below (too long to post all please visit the website linked above if you would indulge with my endeavour, thanks team

```
<ol id="post_list2">

  <li class="article">
   <a href="https://stamprally.org/s/25423" title="北海道 高速道路50周年記念！　北海道スマホスタンプラリー" class="clearfix">
    <div class="image">
     <img width="336" height="216" src="https://stamprally.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/hokkaido-336x216.png" class="attachment-size2 size-size2 wp-post-image" alt="" data-attachment-id="25424" data-permalink="https://stamprally.org/s/25423/hokkaido-6" data-orig-file="https://stamprally.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/hokkaido.png" data-orig-size="860,552" data-comments-opened="1" data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}" data-image-title="hokkaido" data-image-description="" data-medium-file="https://stamprally.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/hokkaido-600x385.png" data-large-file="https://stamprally.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/hokkaido.png" />    </div>
    <div class="info">
    <ul class="meta clearfix"><li class="cat"><span class="cat-category" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category/%e5%8c%97%e6%b5%b7%e9%81%93%e5%9c%b0%e6%96%b9" title="北海道地方">北海道地方</span><span class="cat-category" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category/%e5%8c%97%e6%b5%b7%e9%81%93%e5%9c%b0%e6%96%b9/%e5%8c%97%e6%b5%b7%e9%81%93" title="北海道">北海道</span></li><li class="cat"><span class="cat-category2" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category2/gift1" title="景品あり">景品あり</span><span class="cat-category2" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category2/cost1" title="無料">無料</span><span class="cat-category2" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category2/move2" title="広範囲">広範囲</span></li></ul>
     <h3 class="title">北海道 高速道路50周年記念！　北海道スマホスタンプラリー</h3>
     <p class="excerpt">2022年3月31日まで北海道内の各スポットを巡ってスタンプをGETしよう！北海道の高速道路開通から50周年を記念した今回は、ス…</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="article">
   <a href="https://stamprally.org/s/25400" title="北海道＋東北　海の駅スタンプラリー２０２１" class="clearfix">
    <div class="image">
     <img width="336" height="216" src="https://stamprally.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/umi-336x216.png" class="attachment-size2 size-size2 wp-post-image" alt="" data-attachment-id="25401" data-permalink="https://stamprally.org/s/25400/umi-3" data-orig-file="https://stamprally.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/umi.png" data-orig-size="860,552" data-comments-opened="1" data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}" data-image-title="umi" data-image-description="" data-medium-file="https://stamprally.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/umi-600x385.png" data-large-file="https://stamprally.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/umi.png" />    </div>
    <div class="info">
    <ul class="meta clearfix"><li class="cat"><span class="cat-category" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category/%e5%8c%97%e6%b5%b7%e9%81%93%e5%9c%b0%e6%96%b9" title="北海道地方">北海道地方</span><span class="cat-category" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category/%e6%9d%b1%e5%8c%97%e5%9c%b0%e6%96%b9" title="東北地方">東北地方</span><span class="cat-category" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category/%e5%8c%97%e6%b5%b7%e9%81%93%e5%9c%b0%e6%96%b9/%e5%8c%97%e6%b5%b7%e9%81%93" title="北海道">北海道</span><span class="cat-category" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category/%e6%9d%b1%e5%8c%97%e5%9c%b0%e6%96%b9/%e9%9d%92%e6%a3%ae%e7%9c%8c" title="青森県">青森県</span><span class="cat-category" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category/%e6%9d%b1%e5%8c%97%e5%9c%b0%e6%96%b9/%e5%b2%a9%e6%89%8b%e7%9c%8c" title="岩手県">岩手県</span><span class="cat-category" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category/%e6%9d%b1%e5%8c%97%e5%9c%b0%e6%96%b9/%e7%a7%8b%e7%94%b0%e7%9c%8c" title="秋田県">秋田県</span><span class="cat-category" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category/%e6%9d%b1%e5%8c%97%e5%9c%b0%e6%96%b9/%e7%a6%8f%e5%b3%b6%e7%9c%8c" title="福島県">福島県</span></li><li class="cat"><span class="cat-category2" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category2/gift1" title="景品あり">景品あり</span><span class="cat-category2" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category2/cost1" title="無料">無料</span><span class="cat-category2" data-href="https://stamprally.org/s/category2/move2" title="広範囲">広範囲</span></li></ul>
     <h3 class="title">北海道＋東北　海の駅スタンプラリー２０２１</h3>
     <p class="excerpt">【イベント名】北海道＋東北海の駅スタンプラリー２０２１【日時】令和３年４月２９日（木）～９月３０日（木）【場所】北海…</p>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
```

Comment: Can't use .get_attribute while using find_elements unless you loop.

Comment: li.find_elements_by_id should be css_selector